# Two tables displayed on one page using PHP, PDO and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo, crud

I am trying to create a CRUD dashboard, using a MySql backend and a bootstrap front-end with PHP and PDO to communicate with the database. I am a noob to web development, but not to coding.

The goal is to create a web app to log my patient consults. Thus, my table structure is a single "main" table and two children tables with relationships to the "main" table, named "consults" and "procedures".

I am trying to make a dashboard, where I display my "main" table, and then add two children tables below it. (Later on I will style it better, but I am trying to get this working).

The following is the best MWE I could think of (would love it if someone had a simpler solution). The first "logbook patients" table works well, and displays rows of patients well. Its the second table that is the problem, and in particular:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM proc";
if($result = $pdo->query($sql)){
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
```

This is the area I keep getting an error. The error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/paincl5/public_html/logbook/logbook.php:110 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/paincl5/public_html/logbook/logbook.php on line 110

The code at line 110 is

```
unset($pdo);
```

My full code is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header clearfix">
                    <h2 class="pull-left">Logbook Patients</h2>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >Add New Patient</a>


                </div>
                <?php
                // Include config file
                require_once 'config.php';

                // Attempt select query execution
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM main";
                if($result = $pdo->query($sql)){
                    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
                        echo "<div style='height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;;'>";
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>Surname</th>";
                                    echo "<th>first_name</th>";
                                    echo "<th>DOB</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Hospital</th>";
                                    echo "<th>MRN</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Action</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Surname'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['Hospital'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['MRN'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                    echo "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</tbody>";                            
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        // Free result set
                        unset($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
                }

                // Close connection
                unset($pdo);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>



// Procedure Table
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header clearfix">
                    <h2 class="pull-left">Procedures</h2>
                    <a href="create_proc.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >Add New Procedure</a>
                </div>
                <?php
                // Include config file
                require_once 'config.php';
                // Attempt select query execution
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM proc";
                if($result = $pdo->query($sql)){
                    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
                        echo "<div style='height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;;'>";
                        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>Procedure Type</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Procedure Name</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Notes</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Action</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['procedure_type'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['procedure_name'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>";
                                        echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['id1'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>";
                                        echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['id1'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                    echo "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</tbody>";                            
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        // Free result set
                        unset($result);
                    } else{
                        echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
                }

                // Close connection
                unset($pdo); //Here occurs the error (line 110)
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destroying your `$pdo` variable with `unset($pdo)` so any subsequent calls are trying to run methods against a null object.

Try removing references to that `unset`.

I'm assuming that the `$pdo` object is coming from `config.php`. Since you're using `require_once`, it will only include the config file the first time the `require_once` is called. That's why the `$pdo` is destroyed and not recreated.

Comment: Perfect, I left only the unset reference in the third table (not shown above), and it fixed it. Excellent.